# How to get count of records from the table in single table but multiple timings

Tags: sql-server-2005

my requirement is I want to take count of records from that table on particular date..but createddate column haveving datetime..when I try to count the records it giving multiple records on same date because time is different. How to take count of records on particular day...even time is different?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select count(*),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD,0,DateColumn), 0)
from SOmeTAble
group by DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD,0,DateColumn), 0)
```

example

```
select count(*),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD,0,crdate ), 0)
from sysobjects
group by DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD,0,crdate ), 0)
```